# How to have computed default constructor parameter in Scala?

Tags: java, scala, constructor, default-parameters

In Java I would write:

```
class MyClass {

   private static String id_state;

   final String id;

   MyClass(String id) {
      if( id != null ) {
         this.id = id;
      }
      else {
         this.id = /// complex computation using id_state
      }
   }

   MyClass() {
      this(null);
   }

}
```

How would I write similar in Scala?

Comment: what did you try?

Comment: Why all the votes to close? This question is perfectly clear.

Answer (score 3):

You can have multiple parameter lists in scala:

```
class Foo(x: Option[String])(
  val bar: String  = x.getOrElse(computeDefault)
)
```

(Do not use `null` in scala, they are evil, use `Option` instead).

The downside of this is that will have to add an extra set of parenthesis when creating instances:

```
val foo = new Foo(None)()
```

Alternatively, you can have a "static factory" method for instantiating the class:

```
class Foo(val bar: String) 
object Foo {
   def apply(x: Option[String] = None) = new Foo(x.getOrElse(computeDefault))
}
```

You can now create instances of `Foo` like `val foo = Foo(None)` or `val foo = new Foo("bar")` or just `val foo = Foo()`

Finally, you can have two constructors:

```
class Foo(val bar: String) {
   def this(x: Option[String] = None) = this(x.getOrElse(computeDefault))
}
```

If you insist on allowing `null` (I strongly advice against that), the last approach won't work (because the parameter types are the same), but you can do something like this then:

```
 class Foo(x: String = null) {
   val bar = Option(x).getOrElse(computeDefault)
 }
```

Comment: I don't insist on `null`, I insist on constructor overloading, i.e. have different versions of constructors with different number of arguments (some of arguments optional).

Comment: you can have different consturctors. That's fine.

Comment: Yes, but how to signal to primary constructor, that some value is omited if `null` is not recommended? Companion class is ok I think...

Comment: Use `Option`. `None` would mean that the value is omitted.

Answer (score 2):

You can provide default values inside the constructor declaration like so:

```
class MyClass (val id: String = "One ID to rule them all")
```

Source: https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/default-parameter-values.html

Comment: Default value should not be just constant, but complex computation,

Answer (score 2):

A combination of the other two answers, using default parameters and doing the constructor stuff, which matches your Java code, would look like the following:

```
class MyClass (_id : String = null){
  val id = 
    if (_id == null){
      "complexString" 
    }
    else{
      _id
    }
}
```

Since in Scala, you should avoid using `null` values, you can do something like this alternatively:

```
class MyClass (_id : Option[String]){
  val id = _id.getOrElse({
    "complexcomputation"
  })
}
```

and create the Object via `MyClass(None)` or `MyClass(Some("String"))`

Comment: Is it possible just to omit actual parameter in Scala (without using null, which is not recommended)?

Answer (score 1):

As slight simplification on the other answers I'd suggest this: using an `Option` with default value. That way you can call it as `new Foo(Some("x"))` or `new Foo()`

```
class Foo(_id:Option[String]=None) {
  val id = _id.getOrElse({ "42" }) 
}
```

If most likely empty strings are not acceptable values, then maybe this is an even easier solution - though maybe not as "idiomatic". That way you don't need the `Some()`, so you can use it as: `new Foo("x")` or `new Foo()`

```
class Foo(_id:String = "") {
  val id = if (_id != "") _id else { "42" } 
  // use "id" here ... 
}
```

Edit: I've inlined the "expensive calculation" `"42"` to avoid a method call during instantiation.

Comment: This is definitely the most readable answer. However, I'd recommend NEVER calling instance methods during the constructor (since the class instance isn't completed calling) -- its an anti-pattern and really the compiler should warn or complain against this. Many years ago, the swing library was rife with this.

Comment: interesting - thanks, I wasn't aware this is an anti-pattern! adjusting my response..

Comment: I assume it is. When virtual methods are called in C++, you can only call into the currently-being-constructed methods and its bases, not the virtual definitions in the super classes. In Java (at least, this used to be the case), calling a vfunc from a constructor may call the super class's definition overriding that method -- since the superclass's constructor body has not yet run this may be unsafe.

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to translate your code "1 to 1" to scala it would look like this:

```
class MyClass (private val _id:String){ // default constructor, keeping _id private

  val id:String= //everything that happens in java inside the constructor happens in scala inside the class body
    if( _id != null ) {
       _id
    }
    else {
      /// complex computation using id_state
      ""
    }



    def this() { // alternate constructors are created by defining a function named this
        this(null)
    }

}

object MyClass{ //Companion Object replaces static methods and properties
  val id_state:String = "test"
}
```

Comment: `final String id;` in java code

Comment: Sry, typo, it has been corrected from var id to val id

Answer (score 0):

I think you should assume that callers of your method understand the Scala convention to not use null. This answer attempts to look at the potential use cases of you Java class, distill them down to a few simple rules, and then develop simple idiomatic Scala to address those use cases.

The code below covers two use cases:

- the caller already knows the id they want to use
- the caller wants you to generate an id for them

---

```
case class MyClass(id: String)

object MyClass {
  def apply(): MyClass = MyClass(myComplexComputation)
  def myComplexComputation: String = ???
}
```